# Retrieve from kafka last offsets for each partition in specified topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Kafka gives useful command line tool `kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell`, but I need its functionality in my application.

I want to get all offsets for each partition in specified topic, like that:

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list kafka:9092 --topic com.group.test.Foo
com.group.test.Foo:0:10
com.group.test.Foo:1:11
com.group.test.Foo:2:10
```

But I don't want to run process `bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell`.

How can I do the same using kafka api in Java?
Do I have to create consumer and invoke: `KafkaConsumer#position` for each `TopicPartition`? I need simpler way?

Comment: You can use AdminClient class provided by Kafka. We have a method there describeTopics, which return DescribeTopicsResult. You can find much details there.

Comment: It does not return offset

Comment: Sadly I also couldn't find an easy option. You may need to directly use ConsumerNetworkClient with ListOffsetRequest.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `GetOffsetShell` returns the end offset for each partitions. You could retrieve those offsets programmatically like this:

```
......
try (final KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerProperties)) {
    consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("topicName"));
        Set<TopicPartition> assignment;
        while ((assignment = consumer.assignment()).isEmpty()) {
            consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
        }
        consumer.endOffsets(assignment).forEach((tp, offset) -> System.out.println(tp + ": " + offset));
}
```